# EEEEKK!!11 - A hanging </div> tag in user Activity tab on Area 51 Discussion

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

[image]

[image]

EEEEEEEEEEEEEKKKK!!!!

[Link to my discussion user page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28397/mark-rogers?tab=activity).. EEK!

Comment: No need to be _that_ frustrated...

Comment: @mc10: EEEEEKKK!!!... ... ... ... maybe your right ... ... my god what have I become? :(

Comment: The meme is over.

Comment: @Chichiray: lol, if it wasn't, it is now.

Comment: I'm seeing this on StackOverflow as well.

Comment: @Scott, Oh you're right, that's more Eeeek!

Comment: It's not actually hanging, it's escaped in the HTML itself.

Comment: Yes, you won't see the tag if it is a real tag.

Comment: </div>OH NO IT'S BACK!!!

Comment: I was going to flag this post as offensive for meme abuse, but you get +1 for handwritten typos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found, fixed and de-freakified.